# Improve 3D bounding box query on large set of lines (Postgres 9.5, PostGIS 2.3)

Tags: postgis, 3d

**Problem:** We use Postgres 9.5 and Postgis 2.3 to store about 6 million lines/edges in a 3D space and use an axis aligned bounding box to find all intersecting (and included) lines. This works well, but we want to improve  the query time for larger point sets.

**Context:** Tree-like 3D structures represent neurons, each node has a parent node or it is the root. At the moment we deal with about 15 million nodes, grouped into 150000 trees (many > 10000 nodes). I want to improve existing performance bottlenecks with bigger result sets plus I plan to scale this setup to 10-100x the nodes.

**Setup:** The table storing edges looks like this:

```
=>\d+ treenode_edge
         Tabelle »public.treenode_edge«
   Spalte   |          Typ          | Attribute 
------------+-----------------------+-----------
 id         | bigint                | not null
 project_id | integer               | not null
 edge       | geometry(LineStringZ) | 
Indexe:
    "treenode_edge_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "treenode_edge_gix" gist (edge gist_geometry_ops_nd)
    "treenode_edge_project_id_index" btree (project_id)
```

Note that there is a 3D index for the edge column in place (`treenode_edge_gix`).

**Current timing:** To request 2000 nodes with an typical bounding box size I use the following query:

```
SELECT te.id
FROM treenode_edge te
                               -- left bottom z2, right top z1   
WHERE te.edge &&& 'LINESTRINGZ( -537284.0  699984.0 84770.0,
                                1456444.0 -128432.0 84735.0)'
                 -- left top halfz, right top halfz,
                 -- right bottom halfz, left bottom halfz,
                 -- left top halfz; halfz (distance)
AND ST_3DDWithin(te.edge, ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText(
    'LINESTRING( -537284.0 -128432.0 84752.5, 1456444.0 -128432.0 84752.5,
                 1456444.0  699984.0 84752.5, -537284.0  699984.0 84752.5,
                 -537284.0 -128432.0 84752.5)')), 17.5)
AND te.project_id = 1
LIMIT 2000;
```

This takes about 900ms. This is not so bad, but I look for strategies to make this much faster still. The `&&&` operator filters already most of the existing edges by bounding box test (using index) so that `ST_3DWithin` only needs to check the edges that are most likely part of the result.

The query plan looks like this:

```
Limit  (cost=48.26..4311.24 rows=70 width=8) (actual time=856.261..864.208 rows=2000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=20470
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on treenode_edge te  (cost=48.26..4311.24 rows=70 width=8) (actual time=856.257..863.974 rows=2000 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (edge &&& '01020000800200000000000000886520C100000000A05C25410000000020B2F440000000003C39364100000000005BFFC000000000F0AFF440'::geometry)
         Filter: ((edge && '0103000080010000000500000000000000AB6520C100000000185CFFC000000000F0AFF44000000000AB6520C100000000C35C254100000000F0AFF440000000804D39364100000000C35C25410000000020B2F440000000804D39364100000000185CFFC00000000020B2F44000000000AB6520C100000000185CFFC000000000F0AFF440'::geometry) AND (project_id = 1) AND ('0103000080010000000500000000000000886520C100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440000000003C39364100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440000000003C39364100000000A05C25410000000008B1F44000000000886520C100000000A05C25410000000008B1F44000000000886520C100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440'::geometry && st_expand(edge, '17.5'::double precision)) AND _st_3ddwithin(edge, '0103000080010000000500000000000000886520C100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440000000003C39364100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440000000003C39364100000000A05C25410000000008B1F44000000000886520C100000000A05C25410000000008B1F44000000000886520C100000000005BFFC00000000008B1F440'::geometry, '17.5'::double precision))
         Heap Blocks: exact=1816
         Buffers: shared hit=20470
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on treenode_edge_gix  (cost=0.00..48.25 rows=1044 width=0) (actual time=855.795..855.795 rows=2856 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (edge &&& '01020000800200000000000000886520C100000000A05C25410000000020B2F440000000003C39364100000000005BFFC000000000F0AFF440'::geometry)
               Buffers: shared hit=18654
 Planning time: 3.467 ms
 Execution time: 864.614 ms
```

This shows clearly that the big bounding box test on all existing edges is the problem, though it already makes use of the GiST index.

**Alternatives:** There is one approach that I currently implement to improve this, but I'd like to hear if someone has alternative, possibly better or other suggestions?

This is what I currently try: create a new table that would partition the space into many cubes and store for each all intersecting edges. New, updated or deleted nodes would then lead to an update of the relevant cubes, something that would probably have to run asynchronously. Queries could then pre-filter the space by only looking at relevant cubes instead of using the `&&&` operator with the bounding box of each edge. Does this sound reasonable?